# How to apply different cost functions to different output channels of a convolutional network?

Tags: lua, machine-learning, neural-network, torch, conv-neural-network

I have a convolutional neural network whose output is a 4-channel 2D image. I want to apply sigmoid activation function to the first two channels and then use BCECriterion to computer the loss of the produced images with the ground truth ones. I want to apply squared loss function to the last two channels and finally computer the gradients and do backprop. I would also like to multiply the cost of the squared loss for each of the two last channels by a desired scalar.

So the cost has the following form:

```
cost = crossEntropyCh[{1, 2}] + l1 * squaredLossCh_3 + l2 * squaredLossCh_4
```

The way I'm thinking about doing this is as follow:

```
criterion1 = nn.BCECriterion()
criterion2 = nn.MSECriterion()

error = criterion1:forward(model.output[{{}, {1, 2}}], groundTruth1) + l1 * criterion2:forward(model.output[{{}, {3}}], groundTruth2) + l2 * criterion2:forward(model.output[{{}, {4}}], groundTruth3)
```

However, I don't think this is the correct way of doing it since I will have to do 3 separate backprop steps, one for each of the cost terms. So I wonder, can anyone give me a better solution to do this in Torch?

Answer (score 2):

[SplitTable](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/table.md#splittable) and [ParallelCriterion](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/criterion.md#parallelcriterion) might be helpful for your problem.

Your current output layer is followed by `nn.SplitTable`  that splits your output channels and converts your output tensor into a table. You can also combine different functions by using `ParallelCriterion` so that each criterion is applied on the corresponding entry of output table.

For details, I suggest you read documentation of Torch about tables.

After comments, I added the following code segment solving the original question.

```
M = 100
C = 4
H = 64
W = 64
dataIn = torch.rand(M, C, H, W)

layerOfTables = nn.Sequential()
-- Because SplitTable discards the dimension it is applied on, we insert
-- an additional dimension.
layerOfTables:add(nn.Reshape(M,C,1,H,W))
-- We want to split over the second dimension (i.e. channels).
layerOfTables:add(nn.SplitTable(2, 5))

-- We use ConcatTable in order to create paths accessing to the data for 
-- numereous number of criterions. Each branch from the ConcatTable will 
-- have access to the data (i.e. the output table).
criterionPath = nn.ConcatTable()
-- Starting from offset 1, NarrowTable will select 2 elements. Since you 
-- want to use this portion as a 2 dimensional channel, we need to combine
-- then by using JoinTable. Without JoinTable, the output will be again a 
-- table with 2 elements. 
criterionPath:add(nn.Sequential():add(nn.NarrowTable(1, 2)):add(nn.JoinTable(2)))
-- SelectTable is simplified version of NarrowTable, and it fetches the desired element.
criterionPath:add(nn.SelectTable(3))
criterionPath:add(nn.SelectTable(4))

layerOfTables:add(criterionPath)

-- Here goes the criterion container. You can use this as if it is a regular
-- criterion function (Please see the examples on documentation page).
criterionContainer = nn.ParallelCriterion()
criterionContainer:add(nn.BCECriterion())
criterionContainer:add(nn.MSECriterion())
criterionContainer:add(nn.MSECriterion())
```

Since I used almost every possible table operation, it looks a little bit nasty. However, this is the only way I could solve this problem. I hope that it helps you and others suffering from the same problem. This is how the result looks like:

```
dataOut = layerOfTables:forward(dataIn)
print(dataOut)
{
  1 : DoubleTensor - size: 100x2x64x64
  2 : DoubleTensor - size: 100x1x64x64
  3 : DoubleTensor - size: 100x1x64x64
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the way to do it. When I add nn.SplitTable(2) to my output it gives me a table with 4 elements. Each element contains a 2D image. However, I want to apply a cost function to the first two elements of the table, another cost function to the 3rd channel and another cost function to the last one. How would you implement this?

Comment: Let's make the problem a bit more simple: Suppose I have a convolutional decoder network which outputs a tensor with the size [M x C x H x W] where M is the batch size, C is the number of channels (a multiple of 2) and H = W is an integer number. I want to split the output into a table with two elements each element having the size [M x C / 2 x H x W]. I think it's possible to be done with nn.SplitTable() but I haven't been to do it properly. After splitting the tensors I would like to apply two cost functions to them (this part is easy). Can you give me some hints?